# Use multiple dynamic filters in supabase

Tags: sql, postgresql, svelte, supabase

So i am working on a filtering system in Supabase for a side project, it is my first time using a SQL DB (i was using Firebase before) and I was trying to create some queries like this: [image]

The user should be able to select any filter they want and it should return the filtered products.

This is what I currently have:

```
<script>
...
  let Industries = [
    { value: "Angel Investment", checked: false },
 ....
  ];

  let InvestmentStage = [
    { value: "Convertible Note", checked: false },
...
  ];

  let selectedFiltersObj = {};

  async function getFilterData(filters) {
    console.log(filters)
  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("tester")
      .select()
      .or(filters) 
      .limit(10);

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error.message);
    }

    return {
      investor: data ?? [],
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An unexpected error occurred:", error.message);
    return {
      investor: [],
    };
  }
}



  
async function handleCheckboxChange(key, value) {
  if (!selectedFiltersObj[key]) {
    selectedFiltersObj[key] = [];
  }

  if (selectedFiltersObj[key].includes(value)) {
    selectedFiltersObj[key] = selectedFiltersObj[key].filter(
      (filter) => filter !== value,
    );
  } else {
    selectedFiltersObj[key] = [...selectedFiltersObj[key], value];
  }

  console.log(selectedFiltersObj);


  const result = await getFilterData(selectedFiltersObj);


  console.log(result.investor);
  data = result;

}
</script>
```

and this is how selectedFiltersObj can look

```
Object { Industries: (1) […], "Investment Stage": (1) […] }
```

The problem is that i get Error fetching data: "failed to parse logic tree (([object Object]))" (line 1, column 4)

Does anyone know how to apply multiple dynamic filters to Supabase/PostGres?

Answer (score 0):

Filters need to be a comma separated string: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/or

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('name')
  .or('id.eq.2,name.eq.Algeria')
```